# Which event observer to call for update button action in cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to write a custom functionality when user click on the *Update Shopping Cart* button on the cart page in magento.

In my *config.xml* I am using following

```
<checkout_cart_product_update_after>
  <observers>
    <mymodule_observer>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>updateMethod</method>
    </mymodule_observer>
  </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_update_after>
```

But this event action triggers when I go to the product page after clicking the edit  link in cart page and click on update button.

I want this to happen when I click on *Update Shopping Cart* in shopping cart.

Which event observer should I use?

Answer (score 7):

Use checkout_cart_update_items_before event:

```
        <checkout_cart_update_items_before>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>updateMethod</method>
                </mymodule_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_update_items_before>
```